# Why does Python 'gethostname()' return the entire FQDN when run on a FreeNAS server console?

Tags: hostname, python3, freenas

I get this (FreeNAS 11.2-RELEASE-U1):

```
Python 3.6.5 (default, Dec 20 2018, 21:27:40) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible FreeBSD Clang 6.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_600/final 326565)] on freebsd11 
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information. 
>>> import socket 
>>> print (socket.gethostname()) 
backup-server.example.com
>>>
```

Wha...?

Comment: what is the output of `cat /etc/hostname`?

Comment: ctrl-alt-delor hasn't spotted that the question says FreeBSD and FreeNAS.  (-:

Comment: Depending on configuration, I believe you can also see this while on Linux. I see nothing strange here.

Answer (score 2):

I think it just returns whatever the underlying [`gethostname()` call](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/gethostname.html) does. For example (though this is on Linux):

```
# hostname foobar
# python -c 'import socket; print(socket.gethostname())'
foobar
# hostname foobar.example.org
# python -c 'import socket; print(socket.gethostname())'
foobar.example.org
```

If you just want the hostname part, it's not hard to remove the rest:

```
# python -c 'import socket; import re; print(re.sub("\..*", "", socket.gethostname()))'
foobar
```

Answer (score 1):

Reading the Python documentation, [gethostname](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/socket.html#socket.gethostname) doesn't specify what exactly is being returned and FreeBSD contains the FQDN for the machine in the configuration.

> Return a string containing the hostname of the machine where the Python interpreter is currently executing.
>
> Note: `gethostname()` doesn’t always return the fully qualified domain name; use `getfqdn()` for that.

Other platforms may return only the nodename, but also on Linux this is interesting usecase as the domainname is originally for NIS / Kerberos and doesn't have to match the domainname in DNS.